# Interpret a 4 byte int as a 4 byte float

Tags: c++

Look at this simple program :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
unsigned int i=0x3f800000;
float* p=(float*)(&i);
float f=*p;
cout<<f;
}
```

This is what I expect from the program:

1. Last line: we must see `f` in output.
2. Previous: `f` is the value that `p` is point to.
3. Previous: `p` points to the value that is in the address of variable named `i`. (i.e. to the value of `i`)
4. `i` is `0x3f800000`

So I expect to see the `0x3f800000`in output, but It prints `1` instead. Why?

```
ap1019@sharifvm:~$ ./a.out
1
ap1019@sharifvm:~$
```

Comment: If you print out a float you should expect to see a float, not hex.  Experiment with float f = static_cast<float>(i) and float f = *reinterpret_cast<float *>(&i);

Comment: didn't we just have this question yesterday

Comment: @MattMcNabb I really don't have any idea,As you better know, about 80 questions asked per day in this tag! :) I didn't asked this already

Comment: Why do you expect 0x3f800000 and not 1065353216?

Comment: @molbdnilo Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did is `reinterpret_cast` a pointer to `int` to pointer to `float` and retrieved a `float` value through the converted pointer.

In general, it's undefined behavior, but it so happened on your machine that `int` and `float` have the same size, and the bytes which represent `int` value `0x3f800000`, also represent `float` value `1`.

Comment: and the compiler did not perform type-based aliasing optimizations

Answer (score 2):

> So I expect to see the `0x3f800000` in output, but It prints `1` instead. Why?

Because `0x3f800000` has the bit pattern `00111111100000000000000000000000` that if read according to the [IEEE 754 standard](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) is representing the float `1.0`
[image]

Comment: C++ is not compelled to implement IEEE 754, Pretty picture though.

Comment: @Bathsheba but that's not what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect anything from this code. The behaviour of `(float*)(&i);` is undefined as the pointer types are unrelated.

`float` and `int` might not even be the same size. And you might be working on an architecture that stores `float` and `int` in entirely separate locations in memory. It's even possible that `sizeof(float*)` is not the same as `sizeof(int*)`. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: _float and int might not even be the same size. And you might be working on an architecture that stores float and int in entirely separate locations in memory_ but the memory addresses have equal size, right? (i.e 32 bit or 64 bit)

Comment: @Abraham: it's not actually required by the standard that `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(float*)`, but if there are any C++ implementations where they're not equal, then they're so rare that I expect you'd know about it if you were running the above code on one.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion from int to float is wrong. 
You must do it like this:

```
unsigned int i=0x3f800000;
float f=(float)i;
cout<<f;
```

Answer (score 1):

The bit-pattern that means `1065353216` as an integer (`3f800000` in hex) happens in your implementation to mean `1` as a float. It's not guaranteed that this will be the case in all C++ implementations, although it is common since that's the bit-pattern representing `1` as a 32-bit IEEE 754 float.

Be aware also that your code violates strict aliasing, and therefore has undefined behaviour regardless of the bit patterns.